# Casual equivalent of "broke" or German "pleite"

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Dick Gregory famously said of his childhood, "We weren't poor, just broke."  Meaning, his family was chronically out of money.  In German you can express the same thing as being "pleite."

What's a colloquialism for being *broke* or *out of money* in Spanish?

I'm looking for a word in the same register as *broke*: informal but not vulgar.  A word is okay, or a phrase.  Should be an adjective.

---

I'm not asking for a translation of the Dick Gregory quote; note that *estar en la ruina* is much stronger than *broke*.  *Broke* is for when you've run out of money several days before your paycheck comes in.

Comment: In Spain you can use *estar pelado*. **pelado:** Dicho de una persona: Que se ha quedado sin dinero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you need an adjective, but the one that comes to my mind:

> quebrado, da.
> Del part. de quebrar.
>
> 1. adj. Que ha hecho bancarrota (‖ quiebra de una empresa). U. t. c. s.

requires the copulative "estar", not "ser", and you won't be able to find the pair with "poor" I think you want to form:

- No éramos pobres -- simplemente **estábamos quebrados**.

You also have prepositional phrases like "en la ruina" or "en la quiebra".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, *quebrado* is good -- it came to me a couple hours after posting.  By the way I didn't mean I was trying to translate the Dick Gregory quote.  I used it to show succinctly what I meant by *broke*.  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: En España no se diría *quebrado*, *quebra*r se usa para empresas pero no personas y nunca con el verbo estar. Usaríamos *arruinado* o la expresión "estar en la ruina" que indicas también en tu respuesta

Comment: @blonfu Aquí también podemos usar "arruinado". Al igual que "quebrado", y tal vez aún más, "arruinado" se oye mucho para significar estar mal física o emocionalmente: *Con el paso de los años, está **arruinado***. También tenemos el término (más legal) "fallida" para referirnos al estado causado por la presentación o determinación de una quiebra comercial.